# Project Tasks List in SharePoint 2010

Tags: 2010

I am investigating the Project Tasks List that is part of SharePoint 2010 for use by our team.

I have created the List, and managed to add tasks.  However, I notice that quite a few of the icons on the ribbon are greyed our e.g. Edit Item, View Item, Attach files etc.

I am logged in with an account that has Full Control over the list, but this is still an issue.

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this. I am having the same issue.

Comment: Experiencing the same problem, have you found an answer.

Answer (score 1):

If you have right permissions, it should be enabled when you select the task in the list.

Comment: I wish it was as simple as that.  I am logged in with an account that has full control over the list.  Checked the permissions built in permission checker.  Am also the Site Owner, so this really does not make sense.  
Do I need to enable any features at Site or Collection level?

Answer (score 1):

Do any ribbon buttons activate when you select an actual item in the list. or does nothing happen when you select the item? Could be some custom js that's messing things up.